# Conformal Map wanted

Tags: geometry, conformal-geometry

I am in search of a conformal map that will stretch the rectangle $P_1 =\lbrace(x,y) : (-W < x < W , -L < y < L )\rbrace$ to the entire real plane $P_2 = \lbrace(u,v) : u,v \in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$, where the sides of $P_1$ are mapped to infinity. For example, this transformation:

$$ u = \frac{xy}{W^2-x^2},\quad v = \frac{xy}{L^2-y^2} $$

satisfies the stretching, however it is not conformal. I have almost no experience in these type of problems, so any help will be very helpful. For instance, a good tip may even be the existence of a solution to this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no such map exists: If there were a conformal bijection from your rectangle to the entire plane, the inverse mapping (or its complex conjugate) would be a bounded, [entire function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function). But a bounded, entire function is constant by [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29) from elementary complex analysis.

Generally, no proper open subset of the plane is conformally equivalent to the plane. This is an immediate consequence of the [Koebe-Poincaré uniformization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem).